# I am trying to make a loop pulling from multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, debugging

I am making a simple calculator that, among other things, can provide the user with a formatted history of their previous computations.

```
 print('Formmated as an equation')
 for x in range(len(finalhistory)):
    print(num1history(x) + float(operationHistory(x)) + num2history(x) + ' = ' + 
    finalhistory(x))
    print(' ')
 return
```

When ever this is run though, I get an error saying:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'list' object is not callable
 File "MCT.py", line 34, in BH
    print(num1history(x) + operationHistory(x) + num2history(x) + ' = ' + finalhistory(x))
```

**Edit:**
Should have clarified that the histories called are arrays. `num1history`, `num2history`, `finalhistory` store `float` values, and `operationHistory` stores `str` values.

Answer (score 0):

`finalhistory` is a list. We can't call this like a function.

`finalhistory(x)` -> is the error.

Same for `num1history`, `operationHistory` and `num2history`

You might intent to use `finalhistory[x]`, `num1history[x]`, `operationHistory[x]`, `num2history[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

You index lists with square brackets

```py
 print('Formmated as an equation')
 for x in range(len(finalhistory)):
    print(f'{num1history[x]} + {float(operationHistory[x])} + {num2history[x]} +  =  + 
    {finalhistory[x]}')
    print(' ')
 return
```

You should also print with an f-string

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the code you are using a list and  lists are not callable.
Solution:
Use `finalhistory[x]`...similarly for other arrays